# Provider.of<> returning null with ChangeNotifierProxyProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

In my test code below I have a flag that determines whether to use a ChangeNotifierProvider or a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider. When I press the `RaisedButton` both approaches properly display my GroupEditorPage.

```
const isUsingChangeNotifierProxyProvider = true;

class GroupsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  showGroupEditor(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
        return isUsingChangeNotifierProxyProvider
            ? ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<CloudServicesProvider,
                GroupEditorProvider>(
                create: (_) => GroupEditorProvider(),
                update: (_, cloudServicesProvider, groupEditorProvider) =>
                    groupEditorProvider.update(cloudServicesProvider),
                child: GroupEditorPage(),
              )
            : ChangeNotifierProvider<GroupEditorProvider>(
                create: (_) => GroupEditorProvider(),
                child: GroupEditorPage(),
              );
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliversPage(
      text: 'Testing',
      sliverList: SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return RaisedButton(
              child: Text('+Create Group'),
              onPressed: () => showGroupEditor(context),
            );
          },
          childCount: 1,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But `Provider.of` only returns my GroupEditorProvider instance when ChangeNotifierProvider is used. When Change ChangeNotifierProxyProvider is used, `groupEditorProvider` below is `null`.

```
class GroupEditorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final groupEditorProvider = Provider.of<GroupEditorProvider>(context);
```

I've been using Provider for some time but am new to ChangeNotifierProxyProvider so likely not understanding something fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I wasn't returning the provider instance from my `GroupEditorProvider.update` function:

```
  update(CloudServicesProvider cloudServicesProvider) {
    if (_cloudServicesProvider == null) {
      this._cloudServicesProvider = cloudServicesProvider;
    }
    return this; // <--- was missing
  }
```

Should Flutter have thrown an exception for this? I'll post to github if so.